# Run multiple commands in same cmd prompt - Python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to run say `COMMAND-1` once and `SET-OF-COMMANDS` on several files in a directory. `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` can be used here but somehow I am not able to apply this to my use case.

I should have a cmd promt to open the server on one side and open another command prompt that runs several command looping over files in the directory.

Here is my try -

```
def main():
    # some code
    -----
    -----

    os.chdir('foo.bat directory')

    # START SERVER CMD
    process1 = subprocess.Popen('start cmd /K', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, encoding='utf8')
    process1.communicate(input='foo.bat -s 12345')

    # START CLIENT COMMANDS
    process2 = subprocess.Popen('start cmd /K', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, encoding='utf8')

    for file in os.listdir(dir_location):
          if file.endswith(".ext"):
                 # SET-OF-COMMANDS on each file
                 process2.communicate(input='foo.bat -c 12345 xyz')
                 process2.communicate(input='foo.bat -c 12345 abc')
                 process2.communicate(input='foo.bat -c 12345 fgh')
```

`process.communicate` is not working for me and I get a hanging command prompt doing nothing without any error. Am I missing anything?

I even tried including all the commands in a batch file but the constrain is `COMMAND-1` cannot be in the loop.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: ok, but you need to show how you construct command-1 2 etc

Comment: `COMMAND` as represented here are simple one line widows shell command triggering a `.bat` file with arguments

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I have tried editing as per your suggestion

Comment: `import os` and then `os.system(r"xyz.bat read %s && xyz.bat change %s && xyz.bat call %s....")` maybe?

Comment: Try to precede every `.bat` file with [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) and replace every `&&` by `&`...

Comment: If `'xyz.bat start server'` sets environment variables required for subsequent operation, you need to capture and parse its environment, which is possible if you're careful about Unicode (e.g. run `cmd /u /c "xyz.bat start server & set"` and decode the output as UTF-16LE). The alternative is to drive cmd.exe with pipes to write commands to its stdin and read its stdout and stderr concurrently with two threads. This works so long as you're not running an external command with which you need to interact (i.e. interleaved input and output) but which writes with full buffering if stdout is a pipe.